# Ссылки-редиректы через google.com

Tags: обсуждение, ссылки

Иногда вижу в сообщениях странные ссылки вида:

```
https://www.google.com/url?%куча_параметров%
```

Например, в этом ответе https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/436661/196740

При клике по этой ссылке осуществляется переход на *google.com*, а затем редирект на указанный в параметрах сайт.

Для чего нужна такая ссылка? Насколько она безопасна? И стоит ли заменять ее на ссылку сайта назначения?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Правильнее спрашивать не *"для чего такая ссылка"*, а *"откуда она берется"*?

А берется такая ссылка если в поиске гугла тыкнуть ПКМ на любую ссылку и в контекстном меню выбрать пункт "копировать адрес ссылки". Сам гугл использует эти ссылки для отслеживания переходов пользователей из своего поиска.

Для других сайтов такая ссылка ничего не дает, и только добавляет дополнительную точку отказа. Разумеется, такие ссылки надо заменять на прямые.

Comment: Ссылки, конечно, надо чистить, но считать гугл существенной точкой отказа я бы не стал. :) По-хорошему такие редиректы должен сам движок исправлять.

Comment: @Squidward гугл может сменить формат таких ссылок, сделав разом все старые ссылки недействительными

Comment: Теоретически — может, практически — в гугле понимают, что эти ссылки просачиваются на страницы по всему Интернету, поэтому, даже если избавятся от конкретного механизма или обновят его, то сохранят текущие переходы из соображений обратной совместимости.

Comment: А еще через такую штуку распространяются "вредоносные" ссылки. Приходит, допустим, через скайп ссылка, смотришь - гугловский домен. Значит безопасно. Тык - а там после редиректа сайт казино...